# Android downloadmanager download location

Tags: java, android, download, uri, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download a file from a url to `/storage/emulated/0/Download` using the `DownloadManager`

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setTitle("blah");
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsoluteFile().toString();
System.out.println(path);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, title);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

final long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

And I've confirmed `path` does return the desired Downloads path. My problem is that when the files actually download they end up `/documents/blah` and if the app is uninstalled the files are removed from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, file.name());
```